# Flagged Emails' Body Being Deleted

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

so I have a customer that flags emails as a to-do/follow up tasks in Outlook 365 Desktop. This is completely random but sometimes when an email is flagged it will just delete the body of the email entirely while other emails that are flagged are just fine. Office is up to date on the latest version.

1. I checked OWA and verified the original flagged email is ok.
2. I renamed the OST to recreate the profile.
3. I checked the Microsoft forums but I can't seem to find anything related to this specific issue. They are all referring to the email being deleted entirely.

Here is an image of what is happening. Some info is removed to protect the user.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Jy2zZYC]

Comment: Is this the same issue? (not that the answer is helpful) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1280065/ . Maybe check if your version is the same (16327.20214). Does it happen when running outlook in safe mode, and are they still blank if you view source/view as plain text? Seems like more of a display/preview issue if they show up correctly in OWA

Comment: I will take a look at this and see if it might help. On first glance the issue is the same but the answer given is not definitive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you run outlook in safe mode, will the problem be reproduced?

In addition, the possible reason is that the flagged email has been moved or hidden by a view setting, a category, or a [filter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/flagged-email-mark-complete-email-disappears/cb3abec9-09d0-4436-9a73-3fbb083d15c3) in Outlook. To check if this is the case, you can try to change your view settings, clear your categories, or reset your flag status and see if the email body reappears.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight and see if anything changes.